# Heroku app to automate deploys from GitHub

Tags: git, heroku, github, hubot

Does Heroku allow an app internally to `git clone` (e.g., via a simple bash script) a remote repository locally and push to some other remote that is available?

I am thinking of writing an automated (but manually triggered) [hubot script](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts).

To do this, on Heroku, you should be able to:

1. Run commands (e.g., `git`)
2. Save cloned repository in the filesystem

Thanks.

**Update**

Based on [Benjamin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18640989/11895), I tried as follows, but that doesn’t seem to persist files even between sessions. Any ideas?

```
$ heroku create
Creating obscure-river-7652... done, stack is cedar
http://obscure-river-7652.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:obscure-river-7652.git

$ heroku run --app obscure-river-7652 bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.4427
    $ find .
    .
    $ mkdir -p foobar
    $ touch foobar/README 
    $ find .
    .
    ./foobar
    ./foobar/README
    $ exit

$ heroku run --app obscure-river-7652 bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.5463
    $ find .
    .
```

Comment: Your result from the update is exactly right. What I'm advocating is not creating the private key with a `heroku run` process (because it will be thrown away as soon as you close the console). You need to save the key either when your app starts up (via a custom plugin), or when your Heroku app is built (via a custom buildpack).

Comment: I believe the same goes exactly for cloned git repos or whatever, right?

Comment: Yes, but so long as you pull and push it from the same dyno or `heroku run bash` instance, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work. Heroku has an [ephemeral writable filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which allows you to write data from a dyno. However, when you restart the dyno or start a new one, the data will be gone (because it is ephemeral). However, if you are pulling and pushing at the same time, it won't be a problem.

One thing that may be a problem is setting up your permissions. You will have to setup either your private keys or a username and password on Heroku if you want the dyno to be able to access a private repository.

One method would be to use [GitHub deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys). Setup a deploy key for use on the Heroku app and set something like `heroku config:set PRIVATE_KEY=ABCD123...` with the private key. The deploy key will also have to be present on whatever server you are deploying to. This could be in your [Heroku account](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account#ssh-keys), or in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on a server.

Then, there are two methods for getting this key into your running Hubot instance.

### Creating ~/.ssh/id_rsa with an initializer

Before your app runs, put the data from `$PRIVATE_KEY` into `~/.ssh/id_rsa` with an initializer or some other startup script. This can probably be done with a custom Hubot plugin, and I will look into how that might be done.

### Creating ~/.ssh/id_rsa at build time with a custom buildpack

For a more advanced setup, you can use a custom buildpack to copy the key into the ssh directory during compilation with the [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) feature, the [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) buildpack, and the [inline buildpack](https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-inline).

Enable user-env-compile.

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

Configure your app to use the multi buildpack.

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

Add the inline buildpack and your original buildpack to `.buildpacks`.

```
cat > .buildpacks << BUILDPACKS
https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-inline.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
BUILDPACK
```

Finally, create the scripts for the custom buildpack.

In bin/release,

```
echo '--- {}'
```

In bin/detect

```
echo 'custom'
```

In bin/compile

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
cat > ~/.ssh/id_rsa << KEY
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
$PRIVATE_KEY
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
KEY
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

What happens now, is that when your app gets pushed to Heroku, the multi buildpack will run the inline buildpack. The inline buildpack will run your custom buildpack from `bin/{compile,detect,release}`. This custom buildpack copies the `$PRIVATE_KEY` environment variable to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and generates the public key. `$PRIVATE_KEY` is available because the user-env-compile feature is turned on. Finally the multi buildpack runs the original Node.js buildpack, and everything should run smoothly.

#### Caveats

If you are using this buildpack method, updating your private key with `heroku config:set PRIVATE_KEY=mynewkey`, your app will be restarted, but **not** rebuilt. You will need to either push an empty commit, like so:

```
git commit -m "Rebuild private key." --allow-empty && git push heroku master
```

Or wait until your next deploy for Heroku to automatically rebuild the key.

Comment: Thanks @benjamin-manns! I am updating my original question based on your answer (because apparently you cannot leave formatted comments on SO).